# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/photo_app?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&serverTimezone=GMT
spring.datasource.data-username=suyash
spring.datasource.data-password=suyash
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

SQL Exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) [hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) [hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) [hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) [hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) [hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) [hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) [hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) [hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) [hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175) [hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118) [hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1214) [hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1245) [hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) [spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) [spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) [spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862) [spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799) [spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) [spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) [spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) [spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at com.suyash.mobileappws.MobileAppWsApplication.main(MobileAppWsApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]

Connection to query metadata query:

> 2019-11-17 12:20:32.501  WARN 4912 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>   2019-11-17 12:20:32.503  WARN 4912 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
>   2019-11-17 12:20:32.505  INFO 4912 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
>   2019-11-17 12:20:32.515  INFO 4912 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Application Context error:

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
>   2019-11-17 12:20:32.520 ERROR 4912 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1803) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at com.suyash.mobileappws.MobileAppWsApplication.main(MobileAppWsApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1245) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
>       ... 16 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
>       ... 33 common frames omitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding name and password like this worked

```
# Connection url for the database "photo_app"
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/photo_app
# Username and password
spring.datasource.username = suyash
spring.datasource.password = suyash
# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Answer (score 3):

Step 1:

```
sudo mysql
```

Step 2: check your password. It might be empty or have something different

```
SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;
```

Step 3: Set password

```
ALTER USER 'suyash'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'suyash';
```

Step 4:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now, try starting the spring application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow this user to be accessed from all the host.

Google out this settings for your mysql ui tool and change to the host to % for given user.

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'suyash'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Comment: try this, from the application properties file remove data- from username and password...

Comment: from the error it seems like it is not taking username and password....

Answer (score 0):

Okay so as per my experience there could be a range of problems

1. Check if you're using XAMPP or not. If you are, make sure that Apache and MySQL are both Turned on. If not you wont be able to gain access to your mysql db.
2. If thats all good. Check your config.ini file for mysql. See if your username and password match that of what you're feeding java.
3. If that is matching then it check your code again. Maybe your access is denied because of your database initialization

Answer (score 0):

1)Check your mysql username and password again

2)Check is there exists database called `photo_app` if not create it